# ASP.NET MVC 4 WebGrid. Load entities from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

Should I pass the whole list of entities from Database to a WebGrid to have right paging and sorting functionallity?

What if my database entities list is extremely large?

UPDATE: **I would suggest MvcContrib Grid for everybody. It is very flexible and way better than standard one.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I pass the whole list of entities from Database to a WebGrid to
>   have right paging and sorting functionallity?

No, of course not, that would be catastrophic. You should [`implement paging`](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618) on the server. And here's another [`article on MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx) you may find useful.

Comment: That is good. But is there some out-of-the-box solution, maybe some lib?

Comment: Actually it is absolutely what I needed. I saw this article but was so lazy to try :)